# JS canvas white lines when scaling

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Using JavaScript I am displaying an array on an html 5 canvas. The program uses `c.fillRect()` for each value in the array. Everything looks normal until I scale it using `c.scale()`. After being scaled white lines are visible between the squares. I do know their white because that is the color of the background (When the background changes their color changes too).

Since the squares are 5 units apart I tried setting their width to 5.5 instead of 5; this only remove the white lines when zoom in far enough, but when zooming out the white lines were still there.

This is my code (unnecessary parts removed):

```
function loop()
{
    c.resetTransform();

    c.fillStyle = "white";
    c.fillRect(0, 0, c.canvas.width, c.canvas.height);

    c.scale(scale, scale);
    c.translate(xViewportOffset, yViewportOffset);

    ...

    for(var x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
    {
        for(var y = 0; y < array[x].length; y++)
        {
            ...

            c.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
            c.fillRect(0 + x * 5, 200 + y * 5, 5, 5);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

No scaling:

[image: no scaling image]

Zoomed in:

[image: zoomed in image]

Zoomed out:

[image: zoomed out image]

(the pattern changes depending on the amount of zoom)

Thanks for any help and if any other information is needed please let me know.

**Update:**

I am using Google Chrome

Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: What browser do you use when testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because you are using non-integer values to set the context's scale and/or translate.

Doing so, your *rects* are not on pixel boundaries anymore but on floating values.

Let's make a simple example:

Two pixels, one at coords (x,y) (11,10) the other at coords (12,10).
At default scale, both pixels should be neighbors.
Now, if we apply a scale of `1.3`, the real *pixel-coords* of the first square will be at (14.3,13) and the ones of the second one at (15.6,13).
None of these coords can hold a single pixel, so browsers will apply antialiasing, which consist in smoothing your color with the background color to give the impression of smaller pixels. This is what makes your grids.

```js
const ctx = small.getContext('2d');

ctx.scale(1.3, 1.3);

ctx.fillRect(2,10,10,10);

ctx.fillRect(12,10,10,10);


const mag = magnifier.getContext('2d');
mag.scale(10,10);
mag.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
mag.drawImage(small, 0,-10);
```

```css
/* it is actually transparent, not just more white */
body:hover{background:yellow}
```

```html
<canvas id="small" width="50" height="50"></canvas><br>
<canvas id="magnifier" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

To avoid this, several solutions, all dependent on what you are doing exactly.

In your case, it seems you'd win a lot by working on an [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) which would allow you to replace all these `fillRect` calls to simpler and faster pixel manipulation.
By using a small ImageData, the size of your matrix, you can replace each *rect* to a single pixel. Then you just need to put this matrix on your canvas and redraw the canvas over itself at the correct scale after disabling the [imageSmootingEnabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled) flag, which allows us to disable antialiasing for `drawImage` and *CanvasPatterns* only.

```js
// the original matrix will be 20x20 squares
const width = 20;
const height = 20;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// create an ImageData the size of our matrix
const img = ctx.createImageData(width, height);
// wrap it inside an Uint32Array so that we can work on it faster
const pixels = new Uint32Array(img.data.buffer);
// we could have worked directly with the Uint8 version
// but our loop would have needed to iterate 4 pixels every time

// just to draw a radial-gradient
const rad = width / 2;
// iterate over every pixels
for(let x=0; x<width; x++) {
  for(let y=0; y<height; y++) {
    // make a radial-gradient
    const dist = Math.min(Math.hypot(rad - x, rad - y), rad);
    const color = 0xFF * ((rad - dist) / rad) + 0xFF000000;
    pixels[(y * width) + x] = color;
  }
}
// here we are still at 50x50 pixels
ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
// in case we had transparency, this composite mode will ensure 
// that only what we draw after is kept on the canvas
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
// remove anti-aliasing for drawImage
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
// make it bigger
ctx.scale(30,30);
// draw the canvas over itself
ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0,0);

// In case we draw again, reset all to defaults
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
```

```css
body:hover{background:yellow}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: I did that except I created another canvas to draw onto, and then draw that canvas onto the main one. (Also it increased performance)